# python: Django Page not found (404)

Tags: python, django

app urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path

from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('hello',  views.index, name='index')
]
```

project urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('hello/', include("hello.urls"))
]
```

views.py

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, World!")
```

I've re-watched the tutorial several times and still can't find the error.

Comment: please runserver then go to hello/hello it should appear .. no problem in ur code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your project's urls.py `include`s hello using the prefix `'hello/'` in

```
path('hello/', include("hello.urls"))
```

and your app's urls.py also has `hello` as the path in

```
path('hello',  views.index, name='index')
```

you will need to access `/hello/hello` in your browser to get to a view that doesn't 404.

Django's technical 404 page (the one with the yellow background) should show the available paths -- if you don't get the technical 404 page, ensure you have the `DEBUG` setting turned on.

Comment: Plus add a trailing `/` in the apps url pattern (unless `APPEND_SLASH = False`).